# What is this “(arg: 1)” appearing in terminal/tty after I pressed a combination of keys?

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys

In a virtual terminal I (accidentally) pressed <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and got a new line consisting of

```
(arg: 1)
```

As long as I keep <kbd>Win</kbd> pressed, all numbers I press get appended to the number in the parentheses, e.g. <kbd>Win</kbd> and <kbd>1</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> yields `(arg:14)`.

When I (after releasing <kbd>Win</kbd>) press any key, that character is printed as many times as the number reads and the `(arg: ...)` expression is replaced by the standard prompt.

Does anybody know what happens here?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

That’s a [digit argument](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Numeric-Arguments.html), a feature of the readline library built into `bash`:

```
digit-argument (M-0, M-1, ..., M--)
    Add  this digit to the argument already accumulating, or start a
    new argument. M-- starts a negative argument.
```

This feature makes it simpler to add or delete text in the currently edited command line. Let’s say you want to write `echo gggg`:

1. Enter `echo` followed by space
2. Press the Meta key (which may be <kbd>Win</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> and/or <kbd>Esc</kbd> for you) and type `4g`

But how often do you need to type a single letter so many times that this would save you anything? The feature is primarily designed for readline *commands*, see [chapters 8.2.1–8.2.3 of the Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Bare-Essentials) (“C” meaning <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, “M” meaning Meta).

You can move back one word with Meta and <kbd>B</kbd>, but what if you wanted to move back multiple words at once? You can either hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and press <kbd>B</kbd> multiple times, or use the digit argument:

1. There’s a typo on your command line five words back:

   ```
   $ echo one two tree four five six seven█
   ```
2. Press the Meta key, type `5` and press Meta and <kbd>B</kbd>. Et violà:

   ```
   $ echo one two █ree four five six seven
   ```
3. Fix the typo and either press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to shoot or <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to move to the end of the line again.

You can delete a single word by pressing Meta and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, but what if you wanted to delete multiple words at once?

1. You forgot a word on your command line:

   ```
   $ echo one two four five six seven█
   ```
2. Press the Meta key, type `4` and press Meta and <kbd>Backspace</kbd>.

   ```
   $ echo one two █
   ```
3. Type the missing word followed by space and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to paste what was just deleted. Et violà:

   ```
   $ echo one two three four five six seven█
   ```

<sup>You’re right, you could’ve also moved to there as just explained without deleting anything. We’re on Linux, there are always several ways of doing the same thing.</sup>

And what’s a “negative argument”? It does the same, but in the opposite direction, so Meta `-2` Meta <kbd>Backspace</kbd> deletes the next two words of the command line. “But one could use Meta `1` Meta <kbd>D</kbd> to do the same thing!” Glad you got that, welcome to your command line.

Further reading:

- [Bash Reference Manual, Chapter 8.2.4: Readline Arguments](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Readline-Arguments)
- [Press alt + numeric in bash and you get (arg [numeric]) what is that?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562115/6164712)
- [Time-Saving Tricks on the Command Line](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/time-saving-tricks-command-line)

Comment: What bash version did this come out in ? Looks really useful. +1ed.

Comment: on WSL it's `Esc`

Comment: Wow! I am glad to have given you the inducement for such a great answer!!

Comment: There is nothing to "admit", often when we are talking about things we know already we ('I') tend to not do the research again. Your research makes this answer so comprehensive - including sources.

Comment: What's neat is that digit-argument works, _mutatis mutandis_, in vi-like editing mode (`set -o vi`), too.