# How do I execute multiple commands using the same argument?

Tags: command-line, bash

I wonder if it is possible to make chain actions in Ubuntu terminal like:

```
action 1 on objectA . then action 2 on objectA
```

without having to repeat the name of objectA anymore.

Example:

```
touch file.js && openEditor "$1"
```

or something like that.

Comment: There's plenty of ways to do that, but depends on your needs. What's objectA ? a file ?  What actions we're talking about ?

Comment: thanks, usually a file effectively, can also be a folder

Comment: Here, `&` will send the "touch" command into the background. If you intended "open the editor if touch succeeded", then you want `&&` instead

Comment: Why are you bumping this post? You have already got plenty of answers and even accepted one.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

With bash *History Expansion*, you can refer to the nth word of the current command line using `!#:n` e.g.

```
$ touch foobar && ls -l !#:1
touch foobar && ls -l foobar
-rw-rw---- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 0 Jun 20 14:54 foobar

$ touch foo bar && ls -l !#:2
touch foo bar && ls -l bar
-rw-rw-r-- 1 steeldriver steeldriver 12 Jun 20 14:58 bar
```

Comment: May I ask, which bash version you're using ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy this is `GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release`

Comment: you can also designate [a range of words](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Designators): `touch foo bar && ls -l !#:1-2`

Comment: someone has an idea to use `!#:` as a unix custom command ? I Have tried to create file "arg" with `!#:$1` inside, but it returns  arg: line 1: !#:1: command not found when I'm making something like ` mkdir test && cd arg 1`

Comment: @HoCo_ the `!` character introduces a history expansion expression when you're *in an interactive shell* - it's meant for on-the-fly command line manipulation as you're typing, and is disabled inside non-interactive scripts

Comment: I see... thanks, maybe you know some work around for us ?

Comment: @HoCo_ in a script you should know what the argument is ahead of time - so for example you could just do `arg1=file.js; touch "$arg1" && openEditor "$arg1"`

Comment: @steeldriver thanks a lot, so no so easy to make it on the fly if I understand well IYHO

Answer (score 13):

There is a handy shortcut for a common use case. In your example you are doing:

```
$ touch file.js
$ openEditor <alt>+<.>
```

In the second command, the trick is to write `openEditor` (with a space after it) followed by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>. This will insert the *last* argument of the *last* command, which is `file.js`. (If it doesn't work with <kbd>Alt</kbd> for some reason, <kbd>Esc</kbd> should work as well.)

Since often the "object" is indeed the last argument of the previous command, this can be used frequently. It is easy to remember and will quickly integrate into your set of intuitively used shell shortcuts.

There is a whole bunch of things you can do with this, here's an in-depth article about the possibilities: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009412/how-to-use-arguments-from-previous-command.

As a bonus this will work not only in bash but in all programs that use libreadline for processing command line input.

Comment: You can combine this with a [digit argument](https://askubuntu.com/a/1045169/507051), e.g. to get the second argument hold `Alt` and press `2.` (or `Esc`, `2`, `Esc`, `.`), to get the second to last argument press `Alt`+`-`, type `2` and press `Alt`+`.` (or `Esc`, `-2`, `Esc`, `.`).

Comment: @dessert What if I run want more than one of the arguments? E.g. I run `echo 1 2 3 4` then I want `2` and `3` for the next command

Comment: @dessert Found it myself! You just need to type something else between them, like a space. To concatenate them, the easiest way is to type a space then backspace.

Comment: @wjandrea hold `Alt` and type `2.`, press spacebar, hold `Alt` and type `3.` – if you want a range, use history expansion: `!!:2-3`.

Answer (score 9):

As far as default interactive shell `bash` and scripting shell `dash` goes, you can use `$_` to recall [last argument of the last command](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3371294/3701431).

```bsh
$ echo "Hello World"; echo same "$_"
Hello World
same Hello World
```

[csh](https://linux.die.net/man/1/csh) and tcsh have history references, specifically for the last word of the command, you can use `!$`, and for individual arguments - `!:<index>`:

```bsh
~% echo foo bar
foo bar
~% echo !$
echo bar
bar

% echo bar baz
bar baz
% echo !:1
echo bar
bar
```

In general, it's just better to assign whatever is `objectA` to a variable, and use it in multiple commands, loops, etc. Alternatively, a function could be a choice:

```bsh
$ foo(){ echo "$@"; stat --print="%F\n" "$@";}
$ foo testdir
testdir
directory
```

Comment: I'd just like to point out that `$_` works slightly differently than `!#:n` as the latter is expanded before saving the command in history. So going back in the history would still show the command with `$_` while `!#:n` would have been replaced with its actual value. Both have their pros and cons.

Comment: Also, as usual, `$_` should be quoted, as otherwise it gets split and globbed like everything else. (We just don't see it here since `echo` joins its arguments with a single space.) But e.g. `touch "hello there"; ls -l $_ ` won't work.

Comment: @Dan I think the biggest pro to `$_` is that it's portable. After all, `!#:n` is bash-specific.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend against the history approach given in [steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1048302/91549). This relies on global state, which is always brittle.

Better is to upfront loop over all needed commands, using a proper variabe:

```
$ for c in touch gedit; do $c foo.txt; done
```

What's a bit of a problem in general is that Bash doesn't abort when there's a failure, i.e. this actually behaves like `touch foo.txt; gedit foo.txt` instead of chaining with `&&`. So, to be safe you can add a `break`:

```
$ for c in touch gedit; do $c foo.txt || break; done
```

Answer (score 1):

When cooking up a one-liner, I sometimes assign my repeated thing to a shell variable which I use multiple times in the command.  I can recall and  edit it to use a different arg with up-arrow, control+a, control+right-arrow to get the cursor close to the `t=`.

```
t=testloop; asm-link -d "$t.asm" && perf stat -r2 ./"$t"
```

Note that this makes it easy to tack on an extension, or a variation on the name.

Also note that I need a `;` after the variable assignment, because `var=value cmd` just sets that as an environment variable for that command, and doesn't affect the shell context.